# How to run unit tests on Mac app with sandbox enabled?

Tags: xcode, macos, unit-testing, sandbox

I am trying to run unit tests for Mac application in xcode 5.0 .

The unit tests run fine if I have the sandbox disabled but as soon as I enabled the sandbox the tests are unable to run, failing with error loading bundle (*IDEBundleInjection.c: Error loading bundle*).

I've seen a few other reports about this error and looks like the general assumption is that it won't work. The suggested workaround is to create a new configuration in xcode with sandboxing disabled and running the tests with that configuration.

This works, of course, but it seems like a poor workaround since it will be running the tests in a different environment than the real application normally would and potentially missing on a whole category of bugs resulting from different permissions, directories etc.

I can hardly believe that Apple intended developers to disable sandboxing for testing, seems very short sighted. Has anyone figured out a better solution for running unit tests for an application that is intended to run in sandbox mode?

Comment: Isn't a unit test related to an individual class/method in class?  How does it relate to the entire app?

Comment: The tests themselves are targeting individual units but they are all compiled into a test bundle which is injected into the loaded application bundle.

Comment: Ah, I see.  I haven't used the Xcode 5 unit test framework.